# How to make VectorofVector (2d Vector) that work as two dimentional array in java?

Tags: java, vector

I want to make Vector of Vector object in java that work as two dimentional array. My question is how can we access value from specific dimention from Vector Of Vector.

in two dimentional array, if i want to access value then it can be as m[i][j].

But in Vector of Vectorhow can i do that ?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you don't use `List<E>` instead of `Vector<E>`, anyway it's as simple as:

```
Vector<Vector<Float>> data = new Vector<>();
for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < ROWS_COUNT; rowIdx++) {
  Vector<Float> row = new Vector<>();
  data.add(row);
  for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < COL_COUNTS; colIdx++) {
    row.add(1.0f);
  }
}
```

And then you can access an element with

```
float val = data.get(row).get(col);
```

Note that if it's for a program where performance matter, and especially if the wrapped time is a primitve (float), you'd better use a plain array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i get something out of it. can you add complete code to print the matrix and how i can assign a specific value to an index like in array using [i][j] please...just simple example like 3X3 matrix or 2X2 @Raffaele

Comment: i tried to create 3X3 matrix but according to you example it assign 1 in every element in a matrix so i want to assign my like in array matrix[0][0]=1   matrix[0][1]=3   matrix[2][2] =2  etc...

Comment: You can set whatever value you want `data.get(ROW).set(COL, 42)`. And what about iterating? Can't you write a loop?

Comment: Am completely new in vectors can you just write a sample code with 2X2 matrix assigning and printing the matrix using 2D vector i really appreciateyour help.am stuck for many hours to fix this please just help i have data i want to write in 2D vectors so with simple 2X2 will give me a way to finish this task

Comment: I can give you [this example](http://ideone.com/E0x4dq), but then you really have to study and experiment on your own